# How do I get three div tags to align automatically in response to the user's viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsiveness

This is my code so far: https://codepen.io/mellifluous/pen/GNBbMe

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see all custom css here. So you want to make them side by side for screen ??

Comment: Yes. The idea is that they should align horizontally for a large screen. For a medium screen I want the first 2 div's to align horizontally (each taking up 50% of the grid) and the third on to jump down below the (to take ip 100% of the grid). For a small screen they all need to stack one on top of the other.

Comment: There's too much code to paste here. Everything is at the Codepen link.

Comment: I see your link and post my answer . Please check that out.  and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a Fiddle, I think this is what you are looking for

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNXKXd

```
  <body>
    <p id="main-heading">Our Menu</p>
    <div class="outer-div col-md-4-sm-6">
      <div class="container" id="chicken-block">
        <p class="section-heading" id="chicken-heading">Chicken</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-div col-md-4-sm-6">
      <div class="container" id="beef-block">
        <p class="section-heading" id="beef-heading">Beef</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer-div col-md-4-sm-12">
      <div class="container" id="sushi-block">
        <p class="section-heading" id="sushi-heading">Sushi</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>



*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.outer-div{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 15px;
}
div.container{
  margin:0;
  padding:40px 15px 15px 15px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  border:2px solid black;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
p{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
}
p#main-heading{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  font-size:175%;
  font-weight:bold;
}
p.section-heading{
  font-size:125%;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:0;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:3px 10px;
  border:2px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  right:-2px;
}
p#chicken-heading{
  background-color:#d59898;
}
p#beef-heading{
  color:#f5f5f5;
  background-color:#bd4341;
}
p#sushi-heading{
  background-color:#e5d198;
}
@media (min-width:992px){
  div.col-md-4-sm-6{
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
  }
  div.col-md-4-sm-12{
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
  }
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
  div.col-md-4-sm-6{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
  div.col-md-4-sm-12{
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your codepen you close the media query line 29 (CSS) which don't use the col-lg-* class properly. 2nd you dont define the col-sm-12 width. 3rd you float the col-md-6 at media screen max-width 767px so the last column will take the width of col-md-6 and float it to left. SO I edit you codepen remove the } from line 29 (css part), replace col-md-6 to col-md-12 on last column, remove the media query min-width:768 and max-width:991 for col-md-* classes and just set it to max-width:991. and for media screen 768px replace the col-md-* width's to col-sm-* width. [Edit Codepen](http://codepen.io/tjbaezid/pen/bBxNrq)

**Suggestion:** So basically it's [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) If you use this framework you don't need to write lot's of css. Take a look [Grid System Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and try to understand the view system. Below I Added your code using bootstrap. See the codes and if you have any question ask me on comment.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
   
 h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

p {
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: maroon;
 margin:10px 10px !important;/*I overwrite By default css of p tag so I used !important */
 height: 200px;

 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: white;
}
div[class*='col-']{ /*this css selector get all the class start with col and apply those css into those class which start with col */
    border: 1px solid green;
     padding:0; 
  padding:0px ; /*By default each col-* get 15px padding-left and padding right so I add padding 0 for all those col*/
   
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <title>Solution to Module 2</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
   <body>
<h1 align="center">Our Menu</h1>
   <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id quam blandit.</p></div>
 </div>
</div>
 
</body>
```